# Can't import subfolders from python module on GitHub

Tags: python, python-module

I have a simple python package that I've published on GitHub. I installed the package locally on my machine using `pip`. I am trying to import a subfolder of the module but I keep getting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_folder.subfolder1'`

```
├── package_name/
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── setup.py
│   └── package_folder
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── file1.py
│       ├── file2.py
│       ├── subfolder1/
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── file11.py
│       │   └── file12.py
```

I have the `__init__.py` files in both directories, so I'm not sure why I am unable to access the `subfolder1` files.

I am able to import `file1.py` and `file2.py` from the top-level `package_folder` with `from package_folder import file1.py`.

Comment: Which directory are you starting your script from? Or is this package installed via pip already and you are trying to import `subfolder1`?

Comment: It's installed via pip already on my local machine from GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `setup.py` you have to include the subfolder in the `packages` as well. So, in `setup.py` instead of:

```py
packages=['package_folder']
```

You have to do:

```py
packages=['package_folder', 'package_folder/subfolder1']
```